# Powershell sort PSObject alphabetically

Tags: json, powershell, sorting

Given a custom powershell object (bar) that is created from json (foo.json)

How would you sort the object alphabetically by key?

```
foo.json
{
  "bbb": {"zebras": "fast"},
  "ccc": {},
  "aaa": {"apples": "good"}
}
```

Desired output

```
foo.json
{
  "aaa": {"apples": "good"},
  "bbb": {"zebras": "fast"},
  "ccc": {}
}
```

Example

```
$bar = get-content -raw foo.json | ConvertFrom-Json  
$bar.gettype()  

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

I've tried the following using [sort-object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176968.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

`$bar = $bar | Sort`
`$bar = $bar | Sort-Object`
`Sort-Object -InputObject $bar`
`Sort-Object -InputObject $bar -Property Name`
`Sort-Object -InputObject $bar -Property @{Expression="Name"}`
`Sort-Object -InputObject $bar -Property @{Expression={$_.PSObject.Properties.Name}}`

I've also tried converting the PSObject to a hashtable (hashtables appear to automatically sort based on name), then convert that hashtable back to json, but it looses the order again.

```
$buzz = @{}
$bar.psobject.properties |Foreach { $buzz[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
ConvertTo-Json $buzz -Depth 9
```

**Update**
Changed foo.json to include values aswell as keys

Comment: The json describes a single object, nothing to sort

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) notes, there is no *collection* to sort here, just a single object *whose properties* you want to sort, so you need *reflection* via `Get-Member` to obtain the object's properties:

```
$bar = get-content -raw foo.json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Build an ordered hashtable of the property-value pairs.
$sortedProps = [ordered] @{}
Get-Member -Type  NoteProperty -InputObject $bar | Sort-Object Name |
  % { $sortedProps[$_.Name] = $bar.$($_.Name) }

# Create a new object that receives the sorted properties.
$barWithSortedProperties = New-Object PSCustomObject
Add-Member -InputObject $barWithSortedProperties -NotePropertyMembers $sortedProps
```

A more streamlined version that uses `-pv` (`-PipelineVariable`) to "cache" the unsorted custom object produced by `ConvertFrom-Json`:

```
$barSortedProps = New-Object PSCustomObject
Get-Content -Raw foo.json | ConvertFrom-Json -pv jo |
  Get-Member -Type  NoteProperty | Sort-Object Name | % { 
    Add-Member -InputObject $barSortedProps -Type NoteProperty `
               -Name $_.Name -Value $jo.$($_.Name)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
Function Sort-PSObject {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        Param(
            [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$inputString
        )
        process {
            ($inputString | out-string).trim() -split "`r`n" | sort
        }
}
```

Can send direct from pipeline

Answer (score 0):

A combined version of @mklement0 and @EricWeintraub's answers:

```
Function Sort-PSObjectMembers {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$inputObj
    )
    process {
        $sortedProps = [ordered] @{}
        Get-Member -Type NoteProperty -InputObject $inputObj | Sort-Object Name | ForEach-Object { $sortedProps[$_.Name] = $inputObj.$($_.Name) }

        # Create a new object that receives the sorted properties.
        $sortedObj = New-Object PSCustomObject
        Add-Member -InputObject $sortedObj -NotePropertyMembers $sortedProps        

        return $sortedObj
    }
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
$elements | Sort-PSObjectMembers | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 32 | Out-File "elements.json" -Encoding utf8
```