# How to sort an object by keys using powershell

Tags: json, powershell, sorting

I have the following json file and I want it sorted by the keys/names.  But so far I have been unable to figure out how to actually sort the json object by it's key/name.

Origional Settings.json

```
{
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
  "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
  "editor.tabSize": 4,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
  "editor.trimAutoWhitespace": true
}
```

Code:

```
# Get Json File
$JsonFile = 'C:\Settings.json'
# Convert from Json File to Json Object
$Json = Get-Content $JsonFile | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json 
# Sort Json Object (Does Not Work!!!)
$Json = $Json | Sort-Object -Property Name
#Convert Json Object to Json File
$Json | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Set-Content $JsonFile
```

New Settings.Json

```
{
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 4,
  "editor.trimAutoWhitespace": true
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
  "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile"
}
```

Comment: Hi, `$Json | Sort-Object -Properties Name` displays the sorted lines but does not store them sorted. You need to add `$Json = ` at the beginning for that.

Comment: Or just add the `Sort` to the last line that outputs it. `$Json | Sort -Properties Name | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Set-Content $JsonFile`

Comment: The issue seems to be that the `sort-object -property name` does not actually sort the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer was here:  [Powershell sort PSObject alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056677/powershell-sort-psobject-alphabetically)

This issue was that the json file did not have a collection to sort but was a single object whose properties I wanted to sort.  Below is the code that works.

```
  # Build an ordered hashtable of the property-value pairs.
  $SortedByProperties = [ordered] @{}
  Get-Member -Type  NoteProperty -InputObject $Json | Sort-Object Name |
    ForEach-Object { $SortedByProperties[$_.Name] = $Json.$($_.Name) }

  # Create a new object that receives the sorted properties.
  $JsonFileSorted = New-Object PSCustomObject
  Add-Member -InputObject $JsonFileSorted -NotePropertyMembers $SortedByProperties

  $JsonFileSorted | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Set-Content $JsonFile
```

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
$json | Select-Object ($json | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).Name | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to give some kind of explanation of what this is doing so it's not just a code dump.  This appears to be relying on `Get-Member` to perform the sorting, which is neither obvious nor documented behavior.

Comment: Thumbs up because the code posted worked (for me) and was elegant, but I agree with the comment, an explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Just to sum up for quick copy-past option

```
  $JsonFile = 'C:\data.json'
  $JSON = Get-Content $JsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json

  # Build an ordered hashtable of the property-value pairs. 
  $SortedByProperties = [ordered] @{}
  Get-Member -Type  NoteProperty -InputObject $Json | Sort-Object Name |
    ForEach-Object { $SortedByProperties[$_.Name] = $Json.$($_.Name) }

  # Create a new object that receives the sorted properties. 
  $JsonFileSorted = New-Object PSCustomObject
  Add-Member -InputObject $JsonFileSorted -NotePropertyMembers $SortedByProperties

  $JsonFileSorted | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Set-Content $JsonFile
```

Thanks @Keith for question and answer